# Creating jar file from java form project

Tags: java, forms, swing, user-interface

I created project in intelij, working on froms, and when i create artifact(jar file), my background files aren't readed by program, and not adding to it. And is there any good tutorial for gui programming by forms in intelij?

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) of mine, hopefully it helps somewhat. Though a bit more insight, as to the structure of your project, would be helpful, like some pictorial representation of the same.

Comment: To expand on the link/answer of @nIcEcOw.  Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.